# What kind of paver edging should be used that won't show when completed?

Tags: patio, pavers

I have a patio in progress.  Currently I've got a big square hole with a few inches of gravel in it.  The top surface of the gravel is about 2 inches below the ground, so most likely the pavers will not be flush with the ground, but be about 1 inch raised at the most.

I know I still need to put an inch of sand before I start putting in the pavers, but what would you recommend I use for edging around the patio that can be covered up, or otherwise won't show when it's completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lay a soldier course of the pavers to edge the patio, and then lay a wedge of concrete to lock the soldier course in place.  You can cover over the concrete with dirt after it cures.

[image]

([Image Credit)](http://deadfall.typepad.com/blog/)

Comment: Seems like a lot of work!

Comment: No work is too much if it's the right way to do it. You wouldn't want your paving to shift after 6 months. And this method is rock sOlid +1

Answer (score 4):

Out patio has plastic edge restraints that are placed into the ground with 12" spikes.  They get covered up with the mulch on the non paver side and then brace the pavers on the other side.  Seems pretty easy to work with.

The label on ours says "Paver-Grip Edge Restraint by Unilock" but I can't find that on the Unilock site.  But here are a few alternatives:

http://sek.us.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=58
http://www.pavetech.com/paveedge/edge.shtm

Comment: Really interesting product. Never seen that before. Makes it look easy to pave ;)